# How to Prevent Spring AMQP from Blocking on Unacked Messages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a [`@RabbitListener`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.5.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html) annotated method for which Spring AMQP blocks after returning from the method. The underlying [`SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.5.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.html) uses [`AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.5.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/AcknowledgeMode.html). I don’t want to acknowledge the message in the listener method, yet.

Is there any way to not have Spring AMQP block in such a scenario?

### In more detail

I use a listener like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{ @myQueue }")
void recordRequestsFromMyMessages(
        @Payload MyMessage myMessagePayload,
        @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTag,
        Channel channel) {

    // record relevant parts of the given message and combine them with
    // parts from previous/future messages
    // DON'T acknowledge the consumed message, yet; instead only keep a
    // record of the channel and the delivery tag
}
```

Since I batch/combine multiple messages before I actually process them (asynchronously) later, I don’t want to acknowledge the consumed message right away. Instead, I only want to do this once the messages have been successfully processed later.

With my current approach, Spring AMQP blocks after returning from calling the `recordRequestsFromMyMessages` method above and no further messages are consumed from the same queue anymore.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33017536/1797912) suggests that batch processing should work, however, I’m not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the container that's "blocking".

You need to increase the `prefetchCount` on the container (default 1) - the broker only allows that number of unacked messages to be outstanding.